# How do I reset the control strip on the touch bar to the default settings?

Tags: macos, touch-bar

How do I reset the control strip on the touch bar to the default factory settings? I’ve tried searching for how to do this but have only found information on how to restart the touch bar process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was tested using macOS Monterey.

- Open Terminal.
- Type the following. If prompted, type your password.

```sh
defaults delete com.apple.controlstrip && sudo pkill TouchBarServer
```

The touch bar will turn off momentarily, but the `TouchBarServer` process should restart fairly quickly and the touch bar will be restored to the default factory settings.